# Socket and buffers

Tags: c, sockets

I know standard c library functions fwrite and fread are a sort buffering wrappers of write and read system calls, buffers are used for performance reasons I totally understand.
what I don't understand is the role of buffers in socket programming functions write and read.
can you help me understand what they are used for, highlighting differences and similarities with files buffers?

I'm a newbie in socket programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the kernel receives packets it has to put those data somewhere. It stores it in the buffer. When your app does the next read it can fetch the data from those buffers. If you have a UDP connection and your app doesn't read those buffers it gets full and the kernel starts to drop the received packets. If you have a TCP connection it will acknowledge the packets as long as there is free space in the buffers, but after that it will signal that it cannot read more.

Write buffers are necessary because the network interface is a scarce resource, the kernel typically cannot send immediately a packet. If you do a big write() it could be chopped up to hundreds of packets. So the kernel will store that data in the buffers. The buffer also does a good job if you do a lot of small writes, see [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if you sent your information one byte at a time. You'd be generating a 100 byte packet to send 1 byte, and if it's a TCP connection, depending in implementation, waiting until you got a syn/ack before sending more? Sounds pretty inefficient to me.

Instead, you use a buffer to store up a large amount of data and send that across in a single packet, just like storing up data before writing to disk.

Comment: this strategy is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm and can be disabled.

Comment: @yi_H I knew it had a name :-) Thanks! And yes, it can be disabled if you feel you know better how to send the packets than the implementers of your networking library.

Comment: No, it can be disabled to send the packets immediately. Latency could be more important than wasted bandwith.

Comment: @yi_H You imply that by sending immediately you're reducing latency, which isn't always the case. But this is exactly what I meant by implying that you know better how to send packets than the implementers of the library. The idea is they have it optimized, and you're going to say "No, turn that off - I need it to work differently". That can be dangerous because chances are you (you being the average developer) are not better equipped to solve those problems than the people who wrote the standard networking library.

Comment: It looks like your understanding of the their optimization is incomplete. It's not like that you optimize something and it gets superior to everything else. You need an objective/cost function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28mathematics%29#Overview In this case they optimized it for *banwith*, which is good for most of the applications (so it's a good default). For the rest it's just a hindrance.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm#Interactions_with_real-time_systems

Comment: @yi_H No, I'm understanding it perfectly well. To say it's a hindrance means you fully understand the objectives and the costs. In the hands of most developers, those flags are not tools, but weapons.